# "Property does not exist on type 'never'" when i try to access a json data from API response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

When I try to access `items` fields like `id` or `title` it says *Property does not exist on type 'never'*.

BTW I can see the data properly when log it using `console.log(response.data)`. I followed a tutorial, and it worked fine in the tutorial.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .then(response => {
                setItems(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
    });
```

```
{items.map((item) => {
     <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>
})}
```

Comment: The data is picked from JSONPlaceholder in the Resources section, it's a json.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your code, but I don't think any of them would result in the error you're getting. Can you post the whole components with type definitions you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an interface/type for the `items`:

```
interface Item {
  id: number
  title: string
}
const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);

// OR

const [items, setItems] = useState<any[]>([]); // Do this if you don't want to write an interface or type
```

`useState` accepts a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and returns the stateful value (of the *type* provided) and a function (which accepts the same *type*) to update the state value.

When we don't provide any generic to `useState`, it returns *value* and *function* but with a type knows as [never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).

And that's why you are seeing error:

> properties (id and title) don't exist on type never

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked.  And thank you for all the edits, it's my first post here so i dont know how to write it properly. I will improve my knowledge and i hope i can help others in the future like u did.   Have a nice day!!!!

Comment: Welcome! Happy to edit and answer :) yes, you can help others and StackOverflow community. Have a great day!